# Error when trying to assign a string into a string variable inside a struct

Tags: c, struct, lexer

Im writing a lexer software, but i got a problem when i tried to assign a string into a string variable inside a struct.

```
--common.h--
#define TEST printf("--TEST--\n")

struct Token {
    char* ID;
    char* string;          // String variable
};

struct Token* tokenizer(char* input);

void PrintToken(struct Token* token);

--lexer.c--
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "common.h"

struct Token* tokenizer(char* input)
{
    struct Token* token;

    int toknum = 0;

    int i = -1;

    while (1) {
        char* string;

        for (i += 1; input[i] != ' '; i++) {
            string[i] = input[i];
        }

        strcpy(token[toknum].string, string);       // The problem is here.

        if (input[i] == '\n' || input[i] == '\0')
            break;        

        toknum++;
    }

    return token;
}

void PrintToken(struct Token* token)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", token[i].string);
    }
}

--main.c--
#include <stdio.h>
#include "common.h"

int main()
{
    char* input = "Hello there";

    struct Token* token = tokenizer(input);

    PrintToken(token);

    return 0;
}
```

After I compile the program above with `gcc main.c lexer.c -o final.o` and run final.o, i got an error, it says:

```
Segmentation fault
```

I've tried to replace `strcpy(token[toknum].string, string);` with `token[toknum].string = string;`, but the result is the same.

Is there any way to avoid this error?

Comment: The sooner you realize that "string variable" is actually by a _pointer_ that has to contain a memory address of some memory that _your program allocated_, the sooner you'll stop getting crashes and wild behavior.  Same goes for all your other pointers.  I see no memory management here.

Comment: Here are some additional useful compiler options you can give gcc when you compile your program: `-Wpedantic -fsanitize=address`

Comment: `int i = -1;` and `for (i += 1;` seems pretty bizarre.

Comment: You should turn up warnings. Use `-Wall -Wextra` for GCC. You should get some warnings about using variables without initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an uninitialized variable:

`struct Token* token;`

This only defines a pointer variable but does not assign any valid content. This means the content in indetermioned and reading the content of this variable causes undefined behaviour.

Also this variable does not point to a valid address. Writing to a "random" address via `strcpy` also causes undefined behaviour.

You must allocate dynamic memory for this:

```c
struct Token *token = malloc(sizeof(*token));
// don't forget error handling
```

Then when you want more entries, enlarge the memory:

```c
struct Token *temp = realloc(token, (toknum+1)*sizeof (*token));
if (NULL != temp) 
  token = temp;
else
// error handling
```

Just using an array like this:

```c
struct Token token[x];
```

would reserve memory but you cannot return that address at the end of your function as the lifetime of that object will end at the same time and you may not access it after returning.

---

The same problem arises with `string`:

```c
   char* string;

   for (i += 1; input[i] != ' '; i++) {
        string[i] = input[i];  // <<< string is uninitialized, does not point to valid memory.
   }
```

You do not provide any memory for the string.
Here you could use a local array to hold the string.

---

And again same issue also with `token[toknum].string`.

Your struct only contains pointers. Again you need to reserve memory.
Either you use dynamic memory allocation again or you make `token.string` an array of fixed length.

Your attempt to use `token[toknum].string = string;` would work, if `token[toknum]` and `string` both were valid.

---

There is also another issue in the same piece:

```c
    for (i += 1; input[i] != ' '; i++) {
        string[i] = input[i];
    }

    strcpy(token[toknum].string, string); // << strcpy expects a nul-terminated string
```

You do not terminate your string properly. In this case `strcpy` will happily walk through your memory way beyond the boundaries of your memory allocation until is accidentally finds the terminating `\0` byte.

---

And... what happens if `input` does not contain another space character? This loop will eventuall hit the terminating `0` of `input` and just continue ...

That's two more causes for undedined behaviour waiting for you.

---

That's only what I found in `tokenizer` at a first glance.

In function `PrintToken` you have another issue:
What makes you think, you can print 5 elements of `token`? You never reserve memory for 5 elements and even if you did, you don't initialize the excess elements to contain some empty string.